# How to perform machine learning on data with many trials on individual subjects

Tags: machine-learning, neuroscience

I have an EEG dataset.  The data are epoched around an event of interest and are of the form channels x timepoints x trials.  There are many of these types of datasets for several subjects.  Because the data are high dimensional (many channels and timepoints) I would like to use machine learning.  How do I account for the fact that many of the trials come from the same subject?  Do I violate machine learning rules if I put some trials from the same subject in the training data and other trials from the same subject in the test data?  Is there a minimum amount of subjects I should have to be able to use machine learning?

Comment: What are you predicting?

Comment: Putting the same individual in both training and test data is in effect equivalent saying you want to make predictions about an individual you have seen before, while having individuals only in the test set is in effect equivalent saying you want to make predictions about an individual you have *not* seen before.  These are different exercises, both legitimate in their own way, but you should expect the errors to be likely to be larger on the previously unseen individuals, as they would be if you were not using machine learning.

Comment: I am trying to predict which EEG trials are related to a subject viewing a certain picture (decoding).  Though with this problem it is unclear to me if I want to keep the same subject only in train or test, or mix the trials between train and test.  Is there a particular algorithm that will let me account for the variable subject ID?  Or is there a more appropriate way to solve this problem?